# Fixing language decoding issues in midi files

Tags: character-encoding, midi, string-decoding

I have a midi file of a Chinese song with information given inside the name of tracks. I use a library called MIDI.js to parse it and the output looks like this

```
±¡²`»¡¸Ü¥¼´¿Á¿
```

Where should I look to find the correct encoding / decoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard for specifying text encoding in MIDI files (at least none that is used in practice).

If you know the song is Chinese, you should try common Chinese encodings (GB2312/GB18030 or Big5).